# click event trouble

Tags: jquery, css

I have this slider thing working well with CSS and jquery, with one problem: When I click the first tab thing it plays my animation (see below) but how do I get it to reverse when I click the tab thing again? I don't want to make big changes to my code so please try and keep my code similar just add what I need.

This is my Javascript:

```
$(".guitar").click(function(){
$(".guitar_content").css({display: "block"}).animate({width: "500px"},1000);
$(".guitar_text").delay(1200).animate({opacity: "1"},600);
```

It simply changes the DIV to display and the width to expand to look like sliding. Then the text fades in just after.

Comment: `animated elements must have a position attribute, either relative or absolute.`

Comment: no they dont i am always animating without that. have u got the new jquery library?

Comment: @user1451848 jQuery is adding these styles for you.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [`$.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) function.

```
$(".guitar").toggle(
    function(){
        $(".guitar_content").css({display: "block"}).animate({width: 500},1000);
        $(".guitar_text").delay(1200).animate({opacity: 1},600);
    },
    function(){
        // Reset previous values.
        $(".guitar_content").css({display: "inline"}).animate({width: 0},1000);
        $(".guitar_text").delay(1200).animate({opacity: 0},600);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you want to be careful with this. It's tagged as deprecated, but it's not on the deprecated list, so I'm not sure what's up with that...